# Not able to navigate Camera in VR mode | aframe

Tags: aframe, webvr

Test Environment

- A-Frame Version: 0.8.2
- Platform / Device: Desktop Chrome Version 62.0
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL: https://mohit-vr.glitch.me/

**Description**

In version 0.8.2 , universal controls are not working when we enter in VR mode.
Navigation controls work fine when  normal mode is on.

- Desktop : able to move camera entity using arrow keys / wasd keys
- Mobile : able to move camera using bluetooth joystick

But as soon I enter VR mode , not able to move the camera in either desktop or mobile.

Below is the code for camera entity:

```
 <a-entity
      id="player" 
      camera
      position-listener
      camera="user-height: 2"
      universal-controls
      kinematic-body
      listener
      fov="80"
      near='0.01'
      far="10000"
      position="0 9 0"      
    >
```

I also tried adding movement controls from https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls, but still did not work.

I want to move player/camera in mobile vr mode using bluetooth keyboard { like wasd / arrow keys in desktop view )

Demo :  https://mohit-vr.glitch.me/

Thanks,
Bhupendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [README](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/controls/README.md#usage), you have to set a rig wrapping your camera:

```
<a-entity id="rig"
      movement-controls
      position="25 0 25">
  <a-entity camera
            position="0 1.6 0"
            look-controls></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego , I replaced universal-controls with movement controls and it worked.